# Magento 2: Get store country full name in CMS pages

Tags: store, magento2, country

I want to show the store country full name in a CMS page.

When using:

```
{{config path="general/store_information/country_id"}}
```

It's only showing the 2 letter code. Like "FR".
But I want to show "France".

For phtml/php you can use [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159494/how-to-get-country-name-from-country-code-in-magento-2).

But how to solve this for CMS pages and Blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but you could create a PHTML file from the solution you linked to, then call that from inside your page/static block with `{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::myfiles/myfile.phtml"}}`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But isn't it strange that we can only get the 2 letter code? I really see this as a shortcoming of Magento that this is not possible by default. And it is also strange that this problem is not reported by others (at least, I could not find it).

Comment: @Dennis Totally agree. As someone who's currently migrating to Magento 2, there are _many_ things that seem strange to me...